# How to wrap a specific C ode?

Tags: c, cython

I have a C-function that looks like this:

```
int parse_commandline_options1 (cl1_option_t co[], char ***res, 
                                char ***last_vals, int argc, char *argv[]);
```

I want to wrap it using Cython, but I'm having problems. This is my cython code:

```
cdef extern from "pclo1.h":
    ctypedef struct cl1_option_t:
        pass

    int parse_commandline_options1(cl1_option_t, char***, char***, int, char[]*)

cdef class Options:

    cdef readonly cl1_option_t clo

    cdef cl1_option_t Get(self):
        return self.clo

    property short_name:
        def __get__(self):
            return self.clo.short_name

    property long_name:
        def __get__(self):
            return self.clo.long_name

def ParseCommandLine(char ***a, char ***b, char *c[]):
    o = Options()
    parse_commandline_options1(o.Get(), a, b, 0, c)
    return o                                   # ^ error here
```

Cython tells me that `Cannot assign type 'char **' to 'char(*)[]'` but I don't know that this error means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am no expert, at first glance it looks like you are parsing a pointer to an array, that is expecting an array of pointers

```
int parse_commandline_options1(cl1_option_t, char***, char***, int, char[]*)
```

While the other command is:

```
def ParseCommandLine(char ***a, char ***b, char *c[])
```

Thats why there is a problem in that function as the types are different.

**Suggested Fix**

Edit one of the functions so that they match. I would say change:

```
int parse_commandline_options1(cl1_option_t, char***, char***, int, char[]*)
```

to

```
int parse_commandline_options1(cl1_option_t, char***, char***, int, char* [])
```

This should solve your immediate problem but you will need to update that function if it does indeed expect an array of pointers (if my interpretation of the code is correct).

---

Hope this helps and I am sure smarter people will comment on the real reason! :)